# sending .js file with HttpExchange

Tags: java, httpserver

I have an html file referencing .js file in `src` attribute of `<script>` tag. How to send this .js with com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange, making the client browser find it?

Comment: I fixed it. Actually what was missing is code sending the file, similar to sending the original html, upon the client request with corresponding URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html) getResponseBody() to get a OutputStream to send the response body. When the response body has been written, the stream must be closed to terminate the exchange. Just insert your html response in the body and the browser will process the response script.

Comment: Yes, it was script body what is needed to send this way, upon appropriate request by the client browser.